# Friction Between Magnets

Tags: magnetic-fields, friction, everyday-life

I have heard this definition of friction: "Friction is the resistance to motion of one object moving relative to another." So is there any friction between the same poles of 2 magnets? I can feel resistance when I move magnets past each other, is there any friction involved between the magnets? Is it possible to have friction between objects that aren't touching?

https://www.livescience.com/amp/37161-what-is-friction.html

Comment: Complement to  @Samalama 's answer: Friction is dissipative: doing the same movement backwards creates the same frictional force *in the reverse direction*, so in total you will have dissipated twice more energy. Magnetic force is not: if you move back along the same path, magnetic force will not resist but rather facilitate movement, energy is restored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think friction is a surface-contact force and usually results in conversion of kinetic energy to heat, so the short answer is no. This doesn't mean there isn't a force resisting the motion of magnets, though. I will try and explain in terms of energy, not forces.

When you feel resistance between the like poles of two magnets, this is due to it being a higher state of potential energy. If you move the north pole of one bar magnet towards the north pole of another bar magnet, you are effectively doing work against the magnetic potential. I recommend you look at magnetic dipoles in an external magnetic field: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/magpot.html

As an analogue, you can think of requiring energy to lift a heavy object. You're doing work against gravity by bringing this object to a higher state of gravitational potential energy.